# How to force chapters start by uneven index page

Tags: r, latex, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

I need my thesis chapters start by uneven index page.

My `YAML` header is:

```
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
      number_sections: true
      toc_depth: 4
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}     
  - \usepackage{cite}
  - \usepackage{xcolor} 
  - \definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}  
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
bibliography: biblio.bib
csl: biomed-central.csl
link-citations: true
---
```

Some LaTeX packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No packages, it's part of the [documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6227/how-to-start-new-chapters-on-the-right-hand-side). To do this in knitr, add these to your YAML header:

```
classoption: twoside
classoption: openright
```

Comment: Anywhere in the top level. It's described [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) (under *LaTeX Options*).

Comment: Adding documentclass: book to this option, it works! thanks